# How to distinguish between physical and numerical eigenvalues of an eigenvalue ode problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have an eigenvalue ODE problem of order 4 with non-constant coefficients. The equation doesn't have any analytical solutions and must be solved numerically. So I used numerical solutions(both finite difference and differential quadrature on Chebyshev points) and they resulted some answers. But the problem is that numerical solutions convert the ODE to an algebraic eigenvalue problem ($A x=\lambda x$) on some mesh points; and as the algebraic matrix dimension is n by n(n is the number of mesh points), it has n answers. But I know that the physical(ode) problem should have only 4 roots and other answers are only numerical roots.

Now, how can I distinguish between numerical and main roots.

Comment: Presumably you have 4 clusters of close by eigenvalues, yes? Also, presumably you have some boundary conditions, are you making sure to enforce those, or at least some discretization of them?

Comment: Also, are you sure there are only finitely many eigenvalues? The typical situation in ODE is countably infinitely many eigenvalues.

Comment: @Ian: I have discritized both the equation and its boundary conditions and used them. As the equation is forth order, it has 4 BCs and so 4 eigenvalues. But the algebraic problem results n eigenvalues with no concentrations about any point. also I am sure that I have only finite n number of roots.

Comment: 4 BCS in a 4th order DE does not mean 4 eigenvslues, it says something about the geometric multiplicity possibilities for an eigenvalue (anywhere from 1 to 4). Typically ODE BVPS have infinitely many eigenvalues as I said.

Comment: @Ian: some equations result infinite number of eigenvalues mostly because of trigonometrical functions; but in my case, I have only finite number of answers.

Comment: It doesn't really have anything intrinsically to do with trigonometric functions. You have the same phenomenon with Bessel functions, for example. Anyway, if you are sure (and it is possible despite being unusual, you're right), how have you shown that? Because that is not consistent with the numerical results you're seeing. If your numerical method is any good, the worst thing that could happen is that an eigenvalue which is actually degenerate gets split into several slightly different eigenvalues...which will be very close together when the step size is small enough.

Comment: You could also get very large approximate eigenvalues corresponding to jumps in the approximate eigenfunctions which therefore do not translate into solutions.